# Где брать Одноклассники SDK для Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, соцсети, одноклассники, odnoklassniki-api

В отличие от многих других проектов, у Одноклассников нет "магической строчки", которую можно было бы просто вставить в файл **app/gradle.build**.

То есть нужен JAR файл - чтобы добавить его в проект Android Studio вручную.

В сети есть 2 источника для такого файла -

Первый - в [примере Одноклассников](https://github.com/apiok/android_example/tree/master/libs).

Второй - в [их SDK на GitHub](https://github.com/apiok/ok-android-sdk).

Причем они отличаются - например, у метода `requestAuthorization()` разные параметры.

Я решил попробовать взять второй (после того как с первым у меня были проблемы - о которых я планирую задать отдельный вопрос - но после того, как проясню здесь вопрос об официальном SDK для Одноклассников):

```
git clone https://github.com/apiok/ok-android-sdk.git
cd ok-android-sdk
./gradlew
```

Он пишет **BUILD SUCCESSFUL** но JAR файла нигде нет.

Запускаю тогда **./gradlew signingReport** (пользуюсь, кстати, Mac OS, но пробовал и на Windows 7).

Получаю среди всего прочего

```
Config: release
Store: /Users/afarber/src/ok-android-sdk/ok-android-sdk-key.keystore
Alias: ok-android-sdk
Error: Missing keystore
```

Запускаю **./gradlew assembleRelease** - получаю в конце:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':odnoklassniki-android-sdk-example:packageRelease'.
> File '/Users/afarber/src/ok-android-sdk/ok-android-sdk-key.keystore' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist.
```

Я понимаю, что Одноклассники исключили из GitHub свой файл с ключами для подписания JAR-файла и правильно делают...

Но что мне тогда делать, где взять JAR-файл? (Вкладка "Release" у них на GitHub пустая).

Кроме того, я не уверен, правильные ли использовал команды, если что - прошу подправить.

ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ:

Теперь можно добавить в app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'ru.ok:odnoklassniki-android-sdk:2.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам не нужен jar файл. Подключите их сдк так же как у них в примере на гитхабе, через исходники.

Магическая строчка в градле для этого

```
 compile project(':odnoklassniki-android-sdk')
```